# checking line of a text file in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, compare

I am trying to read 3rd column in my text file without decimal points and output the value using this command,

```
while read line
      do
      Temp=`awk '{ printf("%.0f\n", $3) }' $line`
      echo $Temp
done< final.txt
```

my final.txt file looks like this

> -10.0 -80.0 61.82 20.2163 1.80357 1.68673
>
> -10.0 -79.5 61.82 20.2163 2.80357 1.68673
>
> -10.0 -79.0 63.82 20.2163 1.80357 1.68673

but I get an error like this when I execute my command

> awk: cannot open -10.0 (No such file or directory)

Output  I want to get is

> 61

> 61

> 63

Can someone help me to understand what went wrong in my code please?

Comment: What should the output look like? It is not clear what you mean by "without decimal points" so it would be helpful if you include the output.

Comment: Hello Dave, Sorry about that. I edited my question . I want the output like given above.

Comment: @Monika : the cleanest way would be to write a regex `FS` to strip everything else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a file named after `$line`

```
Temp=`awk '{ printf("%.0f\n", $3) }' $line`
```

which I don't think it's your idea and t should be more like

```
awk '{ printf("%.0f\n", $3) }' final.txt
```

You don't need the while loop.

Comment: Hello Diego, I want to assign the values of final.txt to another variable (Temp) to use to compare with another file. Hence the temp variable~

Comment: It's not clear what you want, edit your question and add expected output

Comment: Sorry about that. I want Temp to give 3rd column line by line without decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

So I edited my code like this.

```
Temp=`echo $line | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $3)}'`
      echo $Temp
```

and it worked !!!